# ssh, fail2ban and max login attempts

Tags: 18.04, ssh, fail2ban

I am testing `fail2ban` in a `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server` in `VirtualBox`. 
I set `maxretry = 3` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, and I tried to ssh connect from another virtual machine with a wrong password. After 3 attempts I have been disconnected with the following message:

```
$ asarluhi@10.20.14.200: Permission denied (publickey, password).
```

On the server side, I checked fail2ban status:

```
$ fail2ban-client status sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 1
   |- Total failed: 2
   | File list: /var/log/auth.log
 - Actions
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |- Total banned: 0
    - Banned IP list:
```

As you can see, `fail2ban` counted 2 failures instead of three and did not ban any machine, while I expected it to ban the machine from which I ssh connected to the server. Consequently, I did not receive any email alert from `fail2ban`. 
 If it was not `fail2ban` to close the shh connection at the third attempt, I wonder if something else (ssh?) did close it before it could be logged by fail2ban. However I tried to set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the directive `MaxAuthTries 5`, but this does not change the result. 
`/var/log/auth.log` says:

```
Failed password for asarluhi from 10.20.14.201 port 42592 ssh2
message repeated 2 times: Failed password for asarluhi from 10.20.14.201 port 42592 ssh2
Connection closed by authenticating user asarluhi 10.20.14.201 port 42592 [preauth]
```

`/var/log/fail2ban.log` instead says:

```
2019-10-30 14:53:24,485 fail2ban.filter  [818]:INFO  [sshd] Found 10.20.14.201 - 2019-10-30 14:53:24
2019-10-30 14:53:24,485 fail2ban.filter  [818]:INFO  [sshd] Found 10.20.14.201 - 2019-10-30 14:53:24
```

As you can see only 2 out of 3 logging attempts were recorded by `fail2ban.log`. 
Also, below is what OSSEC HIDS thinks of my connection attempts:

```
Oct 30 14:53:38 daffyduck sshd[1420]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.20.14.201  user=asarluhi
```

I also ried to set `maxretry = 4` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, but the connection keeps been interrupted after 3 attempts, and `/var/log/fail2ban.log` keeps recording only two of them.

To recap: I now have `maxretry = 4` in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` and `MaxAuthTries 5` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, but still the connection is closed after the third attempt: by what?

Comment: You can check `/var/log/auth.log` and `/var/log/fail2ban.log` to see what fail2ban is doing.

Comment: I updated the original message. It seems that `fail2ban` records only 2 out of 3 logging attempts.

Comment: > message repeated 2 times: < these messages are being together for brevity and to not innundate your logs massively, but in actuality there's 3 messages, just two of them are repeats and are squashed together.  it's stating that the same message as the line above was repeated X number of times.

Comment: I understand, so `auth.log` recorded all my 3 login attempts as expected. However it seems that`fail2ban.log` recorded only 2 of them. No ban was set and no email message was sent.

Comment: I would suggest trying again and allowing some time between the attempts.  This will allow you to trace through each attempt in the logs without them being so mashed together.  There is also a `findtime` variable in fail2ban that controls the "window" during which attacks are counted, but the default for it is usually OK. Also, if you change sshd_config, you have to restart the sshd server (you probably knew that, but better to say it).